RelatedObjectDoesNotExist when trying to count number of objects in a Query Set
I know that this error is not unique to me. I have come across many posts asking what the error is and how to fix it. One of the answers I saw was to use hasattr on the returned objects in a for loop before you try to get the attribute of the object. The problem is, is that I actually want to count() on the QuerySet. I saw some other post use some Django model aggregate function inside of the query, but I don't think that is appropriate or necessary here. The query should be literally as easy as:
font_count = Fonts.objects.filter(origin=location, font_name=font_name).count()

but it says:

my_app.models.Fonts.origin.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Fonts has no origin.

Seems straight forward enough - I'll just open the interactive django shell and make sure that I can't get the origin of the Fonts already loaded into the DB... Well, what do you know?! I can access every origin of every font that I have loaded! What is this garbage?!
I am on Django version "4.1.dev20211216191317" and python 3.9. origin is a foreign key (it can't be set to null values) and font_name is a text field.
Thank you :)

Assuming location is an instance of a type corresponding to the Fonts.origin relationship. Can you try this?
Fonts.objects.filter(origin__pk=location.pk, font_name=font_name).count()

@Vegard, that works. I'm not a huge fan of doing it this way, because it isn't consistent with the other queries that I have in the code, but I mean "eh". Any idea of what the actual cause of the problem is - like why it won't use the query provided?

At first glance I can't really articulate why I had a suspicion that this would work (or why the "logical" way doesn't). What kind of relationship is Font.origin? I made a test case using ForeignKey and your code worked for that.

Actually: Run these two in a django shell - 1. str(Fonts.objects.filter(origin__pk=location.pk, font_name=font_name).query), 2. str(Fonts.objects.filter(origin=location, font_name=font_name).query). If you can get a result for the 2nd line, compare the SQL statements. In my case, the produced SQL was identical. If yours isn't, that points to an issue in either the models or the migrations would be my first guess.

@Vegard They are identical. It's a ForeignKey.

I am at my wits end in that case. Have you restarted your development environment? That'd be my first go-to when all else fails, to rule out unexpectedly stale pycache files and other such problems. If you can write up a complete code example that reproduces the behavior reliably, you could try raising the issue on Django's github.

@Vegard Yes. I can do that by running systemctl restart httpd. Yah, it's weird... I mean, I'm not doing anything different compared to all the other objects that I'm using. Your solution will work for the time being. I'll have to dig into it more when I have more time. Thank you!
